# How to create a subsystem in JetBrains YouTrack

Tags: youtrack

How to create a subsytem type in JetBrains you track?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to settings -> projects
Select your project from the table
Go to fields
Find the subsystem row in the table
Click on the value Bundle